# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am performing a simple API fetch but I am receiving the following error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client` and I am not sure why that is happening:

Code is below and also a print screen of the error is provided. I am not sure if that could be a problem related to the [asynchronous behavior of nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301624/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const myCache = new NodeCache();

let hitCount = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    const allData = myCache.get('allData');

    if (!allData) {
        hitCount++;
        console.log(`hit ${hitCount} number of times`);
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(
                'https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY'
            );
            const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
            myCache.set('allData', data, 70);
            console.log(data + 'This is the data');
            res.send(data);
        } catch (error) {
            res.send(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    console.log('this is the data:', allData);
    res.send(allData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**What I have done so far** to solve this error was:

I used [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) which has a wide explanation of the what the problem could be with a broad explanation of the errors type. However it was not useful to understand what was going on.

Also I found [this useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122272/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983520/express-js-routing-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) but this last one in particular was an error in the code for a missing statement `return`. My error seems to be related to a `TypeError: data is not iterable` but it is not possible because my subscription with the provided is perfectly working.

The closest post I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301624/err-http-headers-sent-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client) which basically states that 
"Sometimes it happens due to asynchronous behavior of nodejs." Now I see this happened to me but I am not sure how this could be solved in this situation.

A log of the error is also shown here in the print screen below for completeness:

[image: error]

What can I do to take care of this error? I did a lot of research and I am not sure how to take care of the asynchronous behavior of `nodejs`.
Thank for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you are calling `res.send()` multiple times:

```
router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    const allData = myCache.get('allData');

    if (!allData) {
        hitCount++;
        console.log(`hit ${hitCount} number of times`);
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(
                'https://api.vesselfinder.com/vesselslist?userkey=KEY'
            );
            const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
            myCache.set('allData', data, 70);
            console.log(data + 'This is the data');
            res.send(data); // <-- FIRST TIME
        } catch (error) {
            res.send(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    console.log('this is the data:', allData);
    res.send(allData); // <-- SECOND TIME
});
```

Calling `res.send()` will end the response so you cannot call it again.

You can wrap the second call inside an `else` condition to ensure that only one is invoked:

```
router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    const allData = myCache.get('allData');

    if (!allData) {
      // ...
    }
    else {
      console.log('this is the data:', allData);
      res.send(allData); // <-- SECOND TIME
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you showed how this can actually be fixed (hint, it just needs an `else` statement added or a strategically placed `return`).

Comment: Hi Steve and thanks for reading the question. The reason why I need both is because on the API I have a 1 minute limit per call and they only way I have to by-pass this is by caching the data. So I have to `res.send(data);` a first time and `res.send(allData);` a second time to see all the vessels.

Comment: As of now if I comment one or the other the program does not work

Comment: I see, so the second one is to send the cached data if you have it. As @jfriend00 suggests, you can wrap the second one in an `else` block.

Comment: @SteveHolgado, thank you very much, that was exactly the problem. It took me a really long time to write the question well and in extracting all the information to post and I am glad the question was clear from your side.

Comment: Thanks it works now and you have been very nice in taking the time to read the question and answer!! :)

Comment: No problem at all :) Thanks also to @jfriend00